# Packging of Edge Extension which support nativemessaging(UWP app)

Tags: uwp, windows-installer, microsoft-edge, packaging, microsoft-edge-extension

I developed an extension which uses native messaging to communicate with backend uwp application. How can I package it?

When I install the package, will it install the edge extension as well which is a part of the package.

Comment: Did you check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/packaging/creating-and-testing-extension-packages)? Seems like pretty detailed description of how to test an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully built a package with the edge extension by the following steps.
Hope this will help you~

Build the project as following structure in C\EdgeExtension\Appx:
[image]

1. fullTrustProcess
If there is fullTrustProcess, the exe should be included in TrustedProcess folder, with configuration in AppxManifest.xml.

```
<desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="TrustedProcess\MyTrustedProcess.exe" />
```

If there is no fullTrustProcess, ignore and delete the TrustedProcess folder.
2. Extension
   JS files of Edge extension are included in Extension folder, configured as following:
   [image]
3. UWP files
   - Assets
   - AppxManifest.xml
   - EdgeNativeMessage.dll
   - EdgeNativeMessage.exe
   - EdgeNativeMessage.winmd
   - resources.pri
4. Package with command

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\makeappx.exe pack /h SHA256 /d  C\EdgeExtension\Appx /p C\EdgeExtension\EdgeNativeMessage.appx
```

5. Sign the appx

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe sign /fd SHA256 /a /f C:\EdgeExtension\MyKey.pfx /p "password" C\EdgeExtension\EdgeNativeMessage.appx
```

6. Install Extension

   - install the MyKey.pfx
   - double click MyEdgeExtension.appx, then click install to install the extension.
7. Check

   - launch Edge broser
   - click ...-> Extensions, 
     System will register the appx, it needs several seconds before the extension shows in the extension list.
   - check registry
     The EdgeNativeMessage will add to the two path.

```
    Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\Extensions

    Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\ExtensionsStore\datastore\Config
```

Comment: Thanks, it got worked for me. Could you tell me how to uninstall the extension, when I click on the Appx again, it installs the extension again.

Comment: You can uninstall in 3 ways:1. Settings -> Apps -> Apps & features -> click you app, uninstall. 2. click Start -> search your app, right click the app, uninstall. 3. Open Edge browser, click ...-> Extension -> click your extension - uninstall.

Comment: Powsershell commands are available to install/uninstall extension. Install: Add-appxpackage <path of your appx: C\EdgeExtension\EdgeNativeMessage.appx>. Uninstall: Get-AppxPackage \*<package name of your appx>\* | Remove-AppxPackage