# Is it possible to package and sign an extension for Microsoft Edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I have Microsoft Developer subscription, since it isn't yet possible to publish extensions in the store, I would like to distribute them myself. Is it possible? Could I sign appx with valid certificate?

Answer (score 0):

I think packaging the appx in sideload mode may help you, you can distribute it yourself. For detail, please see 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps

**For how to create a certificate:**
1. create certificate
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate
Example:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -Subject "CN=BurningFish" -KeyUsage DigitalSignature -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My"
```

You will get path of the certificate, such as A0A89249221A0BA3E8681A12021966475079214B.
2. export the PFX with powershell command:

```
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -Force -AsPlainText 
Export-PfxCertificate -cert "Cert:\LocalMachine\My\A0A89249221A0BA3E8681A12021966475079214B" -FilePath C:\Temp\MyKey.pfx -Password $pwd
```

**For how to package and sign the appx**
I provide a solution in the question:[Packging of Edge Extension which support nativemessaging(UWP app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45793598/packging-of-edge-extension-which-support-nativemessaginguwp-app/45813646#45813646).

**Prerequisites to run the appx**
Set the system to sideload mode:
Go to Setting-> Update & security -> For Developers -> Sideload apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can pack, sign and deploy to the store by yourself: this is known as side loading apps. All you have to do is follow [this process step by step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/packaging/creating-and-testing-extension-packages).

You cannot distribute this to other users, and you can only install on your own machine. Distribution is currently limited only through the store.